# Como desenhar GIF com ImageIO e drawImage

Tags: java, swing, imagem

Preciso desenhar um GIF, tenho o seguinte código:

```
public BasicBlock(String path, String name, int id, boolean gif){
    this.path = path;
    this.name = name;
    this.id = id;   

    File img = new File(path);
    try {
        image = ImageIO.read(img);
    } catch (IOException e) {}
}

public static BufferedImage getBlockById(int id){
    return blocks[id].getImage();
}

g.drawImage(Blocks.getBlockById(id), x, y, null);
```

Comment: Qual é o erro que apresenta?

Comment: Nenhum, o problema é que quando coloco um arquivo `.GIF` ele simplesmente desenha todas as imagens uma em cima da outra, sem a animação do GIF.

Comment: Exatamente essa minha questão, como posso fazer para desenhar animações usando o código que tenho agora.

Comment: Retorna  `The method drawImage(Image, int, int, ImageObserver) in the type Graphics is not applicable for the arguments (BufferedImage, int, int, Map)`; Lembrando que o código está em uma classe chamada `map`.

Comment: Você precisa fazer isso obrigatoriamente dentro do paintcomponent, o `this` é para apontar pro proprio componente onde o gif será desenhado.

Comment: @LucasCarezia você apagou a pergunta, e eu esperava que diminuisse um pouco o escopo, por exemplo, restringindo para a API swing, que já daria pra responder. No entanto, eu estava desenvolvendo uma solução baseada nessa api, mas você deletou, então, pra não perder a oportunidade do que ja ta feito, teste ai e veja se lhe serve: https://github.com/diegofelipem/stackoverflow/blob/master/src/swing/examples5/ChessBoardTest.java

Comment: @Articuno È que procurando na internet achei algo que me serviu, porem eu reabri a pergunta para você responder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apesar de `ImageIO` ser usado para carregar imagens, e um gif também ser uma imagem, o problema de utilizar essa classe para gifs é que ela vai carregar apenas o primeiro frame.

Para carregar corretamente o gif, você precisa criar um [`ImageIcon`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/ImageIcon.html), recuperar um tipo `Image` e passar para o método [`drawImage()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawImage-java.awt.Image-int-int-java.awt.image.ImageObserver-) no `paintComponent()` do painel ou outro componente onde irá desenhar o gif.

Além disso, você precisa também definir um observador de imagem para o `drawImage`, é ele quem irá cuidar da animação.

Fiz um exemplo para que veja na prática:

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class DrawGiFTest extends JComponent {

    public void createAndShowGUI() {

        JFrame window = new JFrame();

        window.getContentPane().add(new GifPanel(loadImage("http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/15inout/duke.gif")));
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 300));

        window.pack();
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    //Este método recebe uma string com a url da imagem e
    //cria um ImageIcon e retorna um tipo Image, com o 
    //gif já carregador corretamente
    private Image loadImage(String url){

        ImageIcon icon;

        try {
            icon = new ImageIcon(new URL(url)); 
            Image img = icon.getImage();
            return img;
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }

    class GifPanel extends JComponent{

        Image image;

        public GifPanel(Image image) {
            this.image = image;
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.drawImage(image, 50, 50, this);
        }

    }


    public static void main(String[] a) {

        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new DrawGiFTest().createAndShowGUI();
        });
    }
}
```

O resultado:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Neste caso, passei o `this`, pois o [`JComponent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html) implementa um [`ImageObserver`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/image/ImageObserver.html). Se for desenhar em qualquer outro componente(como um  `JPanel`, JButton, etc...), você pode passar o `this` também, pois todos os componentes de swing(exceto os [containers top-level](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toplevel.html)) herdam de `JComponent` direta ou indiretamente.

---

**Referências:**

- [Java Draw a GIF](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20924230/5524514)
- [Show an animated BG in Swing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10836832/5524514)
- [Why gif animation doesn't animate when using it in paintComponent()?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11648696/5524514)